# Possible to connect local PowerShell to Azure Runbooks?

Tags: azure, powershell, visual-studio-code, automation, azure-runbook

I'm looking for a way to use my machine-local PowerShell ISE or VSCode to connect to Azure Runbooks. Usually, one has to scaffold locally and then test in the cloud in an Azure runbook. Has anybody ever done this?

One way I'm looking into it is [this idea](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/how-to-setup-and-run-azure-cloud-shell-locally/ba-p/1840528) but I was wondering if you knew of something more convenient.

Comment: Are you trying to connect azure runbook from local PowerShell or VSCode using any script? Or will it be fine using without a script? If you can confirm here, I can provide the solution. @colonel_claypoo

Comment: Requirement is to connect azure runbook from local! Is that the exact issue?

Comment: Looking for another way than scripting directly in the Azure Runbook and at the same time avoiding to have a copy in VSCode where I script and then paste it back to run it in Azure. So basically script locally, execute in Azure. Thx

Comment: If we run any script, then it has to work in vscode as well as Azure runbook without making any changes!! Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***To connect from local (VScode) to Azure Runbooks:***

Thanking @Kaido Järvemets for detailed [steps](https://www.kaidojarvemets.com/how-to-configure-azure-automation-visual-studio-code-extension/). I've tried by considering few steps from there and was able to connect successfully.

- Check for Azure Automation extension in Visual Studio code.

[image]

- To work with Azure automation from local, we need to set up a few settings by searching "**Preferences: User settings**"  (`ctrl+shift+p`).
- Register a new application under Azure Active Directory and add the respective "*client_id, client_secret, automation_account_name, subscription_id,tenant_id*" in extension settings of Azure Automation configuration.

[image]

[image]

- Give the required permissions in `Automation Account -> Access Control (IAM)` as shown here:

[image]

- Created a PowerShell runbook script to run `connect-AzAccount` under Azure Automation Account through portal.

  [image]
- Opened the same runbook in Azure Automation and was able to connect from local (vscode)to Azure.

[image]

**Note**: *Search for Automation explorer* (`ctrl+shift+p`)  and create a new runbook if needed. you can run the same script in Azure portal also & it will work as described above.

[image]

Comment: Finally got around to trying it and it worked. Much appreciated!